# Flutter Firebase Authentication with Github Error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

```
E/flutter (20020): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/] [firebase_auth/web-context-canceled] The web operation was canceled by the user.
E/flutter (20020): #0      onClickGitHubLoginButton (package:catalog/authentication.dart:167:12)
E/flutter (20020): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20020): #1      _CatMaterialIntroState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:catalog/widgets/intro/intro.dart:238:25)
E/flutter (20020): <asynchronous suspension>
```

```dart
Future<UserCredential> onClickGitHubLoginButton() async {
    GithubAuthProvider githubProvider = GithubAuthProvider();
    githubProvider.addScope('read:user');
    githubProvider.addScope('read:email');
 
  try {
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(githubProvider);
  } catch (e){
    return throw FirebaseAuthException(message: e.toString(), code: '');
  }
}
```

Why am I getting this error? The code above is triggered when the login button is clicked. Then it asks me where I want to open the page (in which browser) and the web page immediately closes and the error occurs. When I select a different browser, where I am not logged in, it works. But when I select that browser again without logging off from Github, this happens.